# GUI table widget filling with nested for loops

Tags: python, performance, pyqt

I'm doing a larger PyQt5 project which includes loading in large amount of data into a QTableWidget. However filling the table up with the loaded data is extremely slow due to nested for loops. I put there a minimal working example.
The loaded .txt files usually look like this:

```
...
3.137856026645493124e+00,-1.018072816226149244e-02
3.137333399059442751e+00,2.133285461296379468e-04
3.136810945537534145e+00,6.040261342268495991e-04
3.136288665992822633e+00,6.455403916425843380e-03
3.135766560338420383e+00,3.788118428284327315e-03
3.135244628487498630e+00,3.439159817145511638e-02
3.134722870353285007e+00,-8.456704230609860635e-04
3.134201285849066654e+00,2.062391644217435177e-02
3.133679874888186667e+00,-1.154215762495692556e-02
3.133158637384046763e+00,-3.520437354375163114e-02
3.132637573250105945e+00,4.354430655996290934e-05
...
```

**main.py**

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

import numpy as np

from ui import Ui_MainWindow

class MainProgram(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    x_val = np.array([])
    y_val = np.array([])

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainProgram, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Angular frequency", "Intensity"])
        self.tableWidget.setSizeAdjustPolicy(
        QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)

        self.btn_load.clicked.connect(self.load_data)

    def load_data(self): 
            options = QFileDialog.Options()
            fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,"Title..", "",
                                                      "All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)", options=options)
            try:
                if fileName:
                    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0) 
                    self.x_val, self.y_val = np.loadtxt(fileName, usecols=(0,1), unpack = True, delimiter =',')   
                    """ as you can see I limit the max lines, but even at max 800
                         it's slow"""
                    if len(self.x_val)<800:
                        for row_number in range(len(self.x_val)):
                            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
                            for item in range(len(self.x_val)):
                                self.tableWidget.setItem(item, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.x_val[item])))
                            for item in range(len(self.y_val)):
                                self.tableWidget.setItem(item, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.y_val[item])))
                    else:
                        for row_number in range(800):
                            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
                            for item in range(800):
                                self.tableWidget.setItem(item, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.x_val[item])))
                            for item in range(800):
                                self.tableWidget.setItem(item, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.y_val[item])))
                self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
                self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    my_interface = MainProgram()
    my_interface.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ui.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.btn_load = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_load.setObjectName("btn_load")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_load)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_load.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My question is: *Can this be optimized in any way?*
Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but I thought you overdid it with loops in the `load_data` method.

Try your example with the `load_data` method, which looks like this:

```
# ...

def load_data(self): 
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,"Title..", "",
                                              "Text Files (*.txt)", options=options)
    if fileName:
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0) 
        self.x_val, self.y_val = np.loadtxt(fileName, usecols=(0,1), unpack = True, delimiter =',')   
        for row in range(len(self.x_val)):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.x_val[row])))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.y_val[row])))
    self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()

# ...
```